# The meaning of the clause "The world won't end"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The world won't end if you don't pass a test, so don't get overly worried.

What does " The world won't end" mean?

Comment: It means exactly what it says: the world, the universe, your life keeps on going after you fail.

Comment: I believe it exactly means what it's supposed to mean. What confuses you?

Comment: It has the same meaning as [it’s not the end of the world](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/it-s-not-the-end-of-the-world). It is "used for saying that something bad is not really as serious as someone thinks it is".

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "the world won't end" (usually followed by something like "if X occurs") means that whatever happened didn't matter all that much. That it is not as important as it may seem at first.

Because the world will not end because of it. 
A similar phrase is "life will go on".

Answer (score 0):

"Won't" is a contraction of "will not".

The world will not end if you don't pass a test, so do not get overly worried.

The world is not going to end anyway, don't stress !

Comment: I don't think that was the gist of the question.

Comment: According to YviDe, I understand the meaning of the clause" The world won't end" as "Your life won't end".